# How to open default browser with url by passing post data in xamarin forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms application, and having web url and post data, and I have to open default browser and open url by passing post data.
Can anybody please help which code I can use for this?

Comment: "post data" as in executing a POST request in the default browser from your app? That's not possible. If you mean something else you have to further elaborate

Comment: I need to form a url with post request and open it in default browser from application,

If it is not possible then can you please suggest any other solution for it?
My requirement is to open a external web page with autologin

Comment: If your backend requires a POST request, then there is no solution. You need your backend to accept a GET request. Then you can call an URL with query parameters like `https://www.example.com/login?username=youruser&password=yourpassword`